# Transposing of Dataset

Tags: r

My dataset looks like this:

```
A   B   C   B   E
1   144 119 120 52
2   102 44  97  40
3   128 81  88  39
```

Now I want to transpose the dataset in the following format:

```
A   Vars    Values
1    B        43
2    B        78
3    B       110
1    C        46
2    C        49
3    C       130
1    B        39
2    B        86
3    B       143
1    E        59
2    E       134
3    E        49
```

But when I'm using the following code, one of the duplicate variable is not coming in the dataset.

```
df_transpose<-reshape2::melt(df,id.vars="A")

    A   Vars    Values
    1    B        43
    2    B        78
    3    B       110
    1    C        46
    2    C        49
    3    C       130
    1    E        59
    2    E       134
    3    E        49
```

I can't rename the duplicate variable "B" before transposing, as the location of B is dynamic. E.g. There might be 2 or 3 or more variables before "B". So, each time finding the location of "B", renaming it and then transposing is bit of a hastle.

Can anyone please help me to resolve the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jogo: Not exactly. My problem is not transposing of the data. It's getting transposed perfectly. The issue is while transposing 1 of the variable is getting removed, because they are of the same name.

Comment: `cbind(df$A, rep(names(df)[-1], each=nrow(df)), c(as.matrix(df[-1])))`

Comment: Thanks a lot jogo! This worked perfectly fine for me. Could you please put the comment in the answer section? Then I can mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not pretty but it works:

```
data.frame(A=df$A, Vars=rep(names(df)[-1], each=nrow(df)), Values=c(as.matrix(df[-1])))
```

or:

```
data.frame(A=df$A, Vars=rep(names(df)[-1], each=nrow(df)), Values=stack(df[-1])[[1]])
```

Data used:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE, text=
"A   B   C   B   E
1   144 119 120 52
2   102 44  97  40
3   128 81  88  39")
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something like,

```
data.frame(df1$A, stack(df1[,-1]))
#   df1.A values ind
#1      1    144   B
#2      2    102   B
#3      3    128   B
#4      1    119   C
#5      2     44   C
#6      3     81   C
#7      1    120 B.1
#8      2     97 B.1
#9      3     88 B.1
#10     1     52   E
#11     2     40   E
#12     3     39   E
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sotos! But I already marked jogo's answer as correct. Even though your answer satisfies my question perfectly.

Comment: That's fine @Beta :)

Comment: It seems that the op doesn't want to differentiate B and B.1 in the output. So I would modify your line of code like this: `data.frame(df$A, stack(as.list(df)[-1]))`

Comment: OP already commented on this answer but it is a feasible suggestion. Thanks.